# How to emulate user clicks in WebBrowser or Gecko WPF

Tags: wpf, browser, gecko, emulation

I need emulate some user activity on website with some scrolling, mouse click and keyboard types. The problem is I can't find solution to make mouse clicks and mouse moving in default WebBrowser component. Do you know alternative solutions?

Thanks and sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible option would be to use a client testing tool, like [White](http://white.codeplex.com/), to automate the UI. This may not be the most elegant solution, but it will let you emulate the clicks you need.

Comment: Is there any solution to emulate user activity without displaying page in background thread?

Comment: Then you would have to manipulate your view models, if you use that pattern.

Comment: Or, maybe you could set your window to be hidden and to manipulate it then, but I have not tried that.